# casting void to struct with same format

Tags: c

I have three structs with almost the same exact format.

```
struct name_basics {
    char *nconst;
    char *primaryName;
};

struct title_basics {
    char *tconst;
    char *primaryTitle;
};
```

And one more, but you get the point.
Basically I need a function for each struct, whereas I would like to shorten it down to one.

```
struct nameNode *newNameNode(struct name_basics data) {
    struct nameNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct nameNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}

struct titleNode *newTitleNode(struct title_basics data) {
    struct titleNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct titleNode));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;
}
```

Is there any way to pass them as void, cast them to a sort of abstract struct, and use their data?

Comment: The structs have exactly the same format. Cannot you just use one and rename it to something generic?

Comment: Pass them as a pointer, and have the sub accept a `void*`.  Alternatively, you could use a union of the three structs

Comment: I know it's not the point of the question, but when using malloc, one should check the return value before using it. ~ Beside that, there is no 'clean' way to emulate overrides in C, but some people use macros, unions (technically undefined), void * casts (also undefined in some usages)... I've personally never seen the union way of doing things go wrong and it's usually assumed to work. You can also have, like @klutt suggested, a sub-struct containing all generic fields.

Comment: The tricky part is figuring out which struct i need to cast to though. If all I'm passing is a void *, theres no way to know what to cast to

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the types are not compatible because the names do not match.

Comment: @DarkMonolith. Use any one of them.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — I'm not convinced that C11 [§6 Compatible type and composite type](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7) supports your contention that the types are compatible — they have structure tags but the tags are not the same, and so on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler perhaps "Type Compatible" was too firm a statement. The intent was that while the names differ the 2 structs at issue have equivalent members (e.g. 2-pointers or 4-pointers and a node)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no nice way of doing polymorphism in C. Whatever method you choose, it will at best be acceptable. In your case, since the structs looks exactly the same, I would consider reducing the number of structs to one and rename it to something generic.

But if you don't want to do that, a pretty generic way to do polymorphism is to use a union inside a struct. Whether it's good or bad is up to you. I would not use it.

```
struct myStruct {
    enum {name, title} type;
    union {
        struct name_basics a;
        struct title_basics b;
    } data;
};

void *newNode(struct myStruct data) {
    struct nameNode *nn;
    struct titleNode *tn;
    void *ret;
    switch(data.type) {
    case name:
        nn = malloc(sizeof(struct name_basics));
        nn->data = data.data.a;
        nn->left = nn->right = NULL;
        ret = (void*)nn;
        break;
    case title:
        tn = malloc(sizeof(struct title_basics));
        tn->data = data.data.b;
        tn->left = tn->right = NULL;
        ret = (void*)tn;
        break;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Some of this could be simplified in your case because the structs are so similar, but this is a generic way.

Comment: In what way is it better than having separate independent functions?

Comment: @n.m. I did not say it was better, but that's what OP asked for.

Comment: OP already has something, upon which they want to improve. If your proposal is not an improvement, why make it?

Comment: @n.m. Whether it's an improvement or not is subjective, and in order to have an actual opinion in the matter I would need to see more code. But OP said *"Basically I need a function for each struct, whereas **I would like to shorten it down to one.**"*

Comment: OP asked for an improvement. If it is not an improvement *in your opinion*, do not suggest it. Is it an improvement *in your opinion*? That is, would *you* genuinely use it in *your* code? There's nothing subjective about it.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to shorten anything down, and comes with a hist of problems of its own.

Comment: OP did not ask for general improvement. If they did, codereview would be a better place anyway. Here, OP specifically asked for how to shorten it down to *one function*. They did not ask for how to shorten down the amount of lines. Now, do you see anything specific that I have missed here or do you just dislike the whole concept? Maybe you even have a better answer? Feel free to add it.

Comment: Making a big function out of several smaller ones is an excellent way to get yourself laughed out of a job interview or make your commit reverted with prejudice. So this answer is "here is your way to get screwed, because you have not explicitly asked to not get screwed".

Comment: Yes I do see probkem with yoir code. There is absoitely no reason to have it, other than the misguided idea that smaller function count wth larger line count is better. The original many-functions code is easier to read and less error-prone.

Comment: @n.m. I added a line about not recommending it. (Funny, I thought I already had but I must have missed it) Nevertheless, I don't see anything wrong in showing how something can be done, even though it's not advisable. I have seen loads of such answers here, and I find them very interesting to read.